# Run N Promises with parallel limitation

Tags: javascript, promise, coffeescript

So, I am trying to run N promises with parallel count limitation. I want to have for example 3 promises waiting callback while my program works. Not more, but still could be a situation, when 2 promises at work (example - N = 5, 3 in parallel, so at the end of program there will be only 2 promises, and it's OK)

Without `yield sleep 1` this code does not work, it will start 3 funcs add, log 3 "#{name about to create}" and it's all. Program will stay in this state as long as you can wait.

But with `yield sleep 1` it works fine.

Why?

```
co = require 'co'
Promise = require "bluebird"

in_progress = 0
check_num = 0
checks_list = []

add = (name) ->
    console.log "#{name} about to create"
    in_progress++
    new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
        setTimeout () ->
            console.log "#{name} completed"
            in_progress--
            resolve(name)
        , 3000

sleep = (t) ->
    new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
        setTimeout ->
            resolve()
        , t

run = () -> co ->
    while check_num < 5
        console.log "in progress: #{in_progress}"
        if in_progress < 3
            checks_list.push add("n#{check_num++}")
        # yield sleep 1


run().then () ->
    console.log checks_list

    Promise.all checks_list
    .then () ->
        console.log checks_list
```

P.S.This question duplicates [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886598/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-n-promise-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-k-promise) but it's in Russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `yield`ing, you just have an infinite loop. The `setTimeout` callback can never happen, the promises will never resolve, and your loop counter will never change. With the `yield sleep 1`, the loop is interrupted on every iteration, allowing other stuff to happen, which will eventually decrease `in_progress` and allow more `add` promises to be created until `check_num` is 5.

Notice that since you are using Bluebird, you don't need any of this, you don't even need `co`:

```
Promise = require "bluebird"

add = Promise.coroutine (name) ->
    console.log "#{name} about to create"
    yield Promise.delay 3000
    console.log "#{name} completed"

Promise.map ("n#{check_num}" for check_num in [0..5]),
            add,
            concurrency: 3
.then ->
    console.log "all done"
```